# Can't start 32-bit DLL in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have an issue with VS2015.

I want to create a DLL that reads through .csv file, and for this, I'll use the Jet ADO Provider, but it only works in 32-bits.

Therefore, I am trying to execute a 32-bit DLL on my 64 bit windows 7.

I have created a Class Library Project, with an empty UserControl. No external reference, no code whatsoever.

If I run in "Any CPU" or "x64", everything works fine.
If I set the target CPU to "x86", it won't lauch, with error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

In the console, I can read:

```
'UserControlTestContainer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

It seems to indicate that mscorlib.dll is loaded from a 64-bit folder, although I am in 32-bit, and I haven't found where to change this.

Could you please help me fix this?

Regards,
Maxime

Comment: is it a library or an application? if it's a library, then you surely have another project, which is an application dependent on it. is this project also set to 32 bit?

Comment: It's a class library project, there is nothing else.

Comment: you cannot execute a library, how are you running it? line from your console suggests that you are using some sort of external application named `UserControlTestContainer.exe`. is it 32bit as well?

Comment: Should be obvious from the load message, "GAC_64" leaves nothing to the imagination.  You did not actually manage to set the target platform correctly.  Standard mistake is to pay too much attention to the solution platform setting, it is irrelevant for managed projects.  Only the setting in Project > Properties > Build tab matters.  And only for the EXE project.  And be sure to change it both for the Debug and the Release build.

Comment: I don't have an exe project. I think that VS2015 creates an ad-hoc exe project with default parameters.

I'll try to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on the question, I managed to get it to work:

- In VS2015, it is possible to run a Class Library without .exe project.
- When a Class Library is run without a .exe project, an ad-hoc project is created, with standard configuration: "UserControlTestContainer.exe". On a 64-bit system, it is executed as a 64-bit application.
- In order to execute a 32-bit DLL, a user-made exe project, set up to 32-bit is needed.

Comment: It's a nice new feature of VS2015 I guess. Please double check if you can configure this "Container" ad-hoc project to run as x86